# Measuring work by lifting cable with constant weight

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity

At calculus - an intuitive and physical approach by Morris Kline(2nd edition) 143p,

> 6. A cable weighing 2 pounds per foot of length (and so having a mass of 2 pounds per foot) is suspended from the top of a well 200 feet deep and extends to the bottom. Find the work done in raising the cable to the surface. Over the distance of 200 feet you may use $32m$ as the constant weight of a mass $m$.

And according to the solutions manual to the book,

> 6. Measure $r$ downward from the top of the well. Then the force on a length of cable of length $r$ is the force (weight) per unit length times $r$. Thus $F = 32mr = 64r$. Using the relation $\frac {dW}{dr} = F$ derived in the text, we find (since $W = 0$ for $r = 0$), $W = 32r^2$. Thus the work to lift the entire cable is $32(200)^2 = 1,280,000\;ft-pdl$.

I don't understand the solution. The independent variable $r$ in $\frac {dW} {dr} = F$ origianlly means a distance between two objects. But the writer of solution used $r$ for the length of the cable. In this equation $\frac {dW}{dr} = F = 32mr  = 64r$ I think $r$ in $\frac{dW}{dr}$ and $r$ in $64r$ are different. Therefore I think the integration $W = 32r^2 + C$ doesn't make sense at all. Am I right?

My attempt: $F$ is constant by the question's property `you may use 32m as the constant weight of a mass m`. So $W = F·s = (32·400)·(200) = 2,560,000\;ft-pdl$.

Comment: The force is not constant. You only apply a force equal to the weight of the 200 ft cable at the very beginiing. As less cable is hanging the force is less.

Comment: I like this style of question. Shows the person is sincere and seeking knowledge. Best possible use of our screwing around online. Why on earth it got downvoted? Lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$w=32m$ is the constant weight of a given mass m. But our mass changes. So your way isnt right. They just meant the constant you use to get force is 32.

Think of it this alternate way first then we’ll see their way:
r is how much cable is out there. $F=32(2r)=64r$ and r goes from 200 at the beginning down to 0 when done reeling in. So the force being moved is changing the whole way. Work=Force times distance-moved. For any r we are at, for a tiny bit to reel in dx, the tiny amount of work is $dw= F dx = 64r dx$ (again, that’s true for any r).

But dx and dr are the same thing except opposite, because for every little bit we reel in (for every bit of positive distance dx moved under load) the rope is shorter by that much, dx= -dr. So $dw= -64r dr$.

Any differential is the change in something, positive means increase, so that $-dr$ means “decreasing”.

To add up these tiny changes we integrate:

$W = \int_{200}^0 (-64r) dr $ (cuz we *start* at 200 and *end* at 0)

$= (-32 \cdot 0^2) - (-32 \cdot 200^2) = $ his answer

(His way is force equals change in work per unit distance, which is a stupid way to try and set-up problems. It represents a situation where force and distance change a little. Not intuitive. But we still can. F = dw/dr, multiply both sides by dr: Fdr= dW. F=64r. Integrate both sides.)